# Java Swing JPopupMenu setVisible(false) doesn't work

Tags: java, swing, jpopupmenu

I have a class MyPopupMenu that extends JPopupMenu. Inside this popup menu I add a JMenuItem with an ActionListener which calls a process that it takes some minutes to return. I would like to make the popup menu close right after this item is pressed. My method inside the MyPopupMenu class is this:

```
private JMenuItem newItem(){
    JMenuItem item=new JMenuItem();
    item.setText("One");
    item.setToolTipText("One");
    ActionListener mylistener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            MyPopupMenu.this.setVisible(false);
            Class1 class1=new Class1(file);
            try {
                class1.start();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    item.addActionListener(mylistener);
    return item;
}
```

This doesn't work. After I press the item "One" the process starts but the popup menu remains open until the process returns (for some minutes). Is it possible to make the the popup menu disappear but the process continue running?

Comment: GUI updates are handled by the thread where the action listener is run. You should run long running tasks in a background thread, for example using a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html).

Comment: Thanks! I used SwingWorker and it works as expected!

Answer (score 0):

You are performing an action on the Swing main thread. This blocks your Gui from updating. You should move the starting of you class into another Thread.

For more info see [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/)